How to simulate an independent current source pulse in LTspice
I am trying to simulate an independent current source pulse in LTspice but it is not behaving as expected. I want the pulse to stay on for 10 ns but it just goes immediately on an off. I am not sure the issue.


Ty to use this settings PULSE(0 1 0 1p 1p 10n)

You have several problems.
First, you have \$T_{period}\$ set to 0. This will give you a pulse with no time, it stops as soon as it starts so all you might see is a little glitch at the beginning.
You can set this to a time, something longer than \$T_{on}\$. This will set a repeat rate and give you an astable pulse train. The number of pulses can be set with \$N_{cycles}\$. If you leave \$T_{period}\$ blank it will default to something like infinity and you will get a single pulse.
Next, you have \$T_{rise}\$ and \$T_{fall}\$ set to 0. This will give you the default value which is not zero (I'm seeing 1 ns), and for a 10 ns pulse will probably be too long and give you a pulse with sloped edges. You can set it to something small compared to your pulse width, maybe 1p or even 1f, this will give you a reasonable looking square pulse. Note that rise and fall times will be added to the pulse width, so if you have an on time of 10 ns and rise and fall times of 1 ns the total width will be 12 ns.
Last, you have the initial current as 10 µA and on current as 0 A, this may be what you want, you'll have a 10 µA baseline and the pulse will go low from that. If you want a positive going pulse swap the two values.
If you want to get a better look at the beginning of the pulse you can set \$T_{delay}\$ to some value, maybe 1 ns.
Here's an example with the pulse command PULSE(0 10u 10n 1n 1n 10n 15n 3)

The waveform starts with the current at I1 and has a delay of 10 ns, at that point the rise time of 1 ns starts and it rises to I2. It remains at I2 for \$T_{on}\$, 10 ns, then falls to I1 in the fall time of 1 ns. At this point it is at 22 ns, it stays at I1 until \$T_{period}\$expires, 15 ns after the beginning of the pulse, and then the next pulse starts. \$N_{cycles}\$ sets the number of pulses to 3 and after that the current remains at I1.

Default value for tr and tf (if 0 is set) is  10% of Ton or 10% of Tperiod-Ton whatever is smaller.  See here

You need a period, the period is how long the whole cycle of the pulse is. The Ton is how long the signal stays 'on' for. If you wanted 50% PWM, then you would need a period of 20ns and 10ns for the pulse.
A 33% duty cycle would be 30ns for the period and 10ns for the pulse.
You also need to define I1 and I2 correctly (which is usually on and off)
Here is my example:


Wrong. Notice that the initial value i 10uA and the "finally" value is 0A, also a lack of rising and falling time.

You don't have to have rising and falling time, it's a good idea for most applications to include it.

You don’t need a period unless you want more than one pulse. The question mentions pulse singularly so they may not want to set a period, in which case their mistake was setting it to 0 rather than leaving it blank. I1 and I2 just define the off state and on state values, you wouldn’t want to make them the same but other than that pretty much anything goes, so the values in the question aren’t necessarily wrong.
